# distinct or unique count in multiple filter on access split form

Tags: vba, ms-access, filtering

[image]i am making a form for extracting data from access datasheet. i try to filter the data of between date range, status, area, contractor, project type and also calculation of total by different distinct field. i write some vba code but not fully success. i can upload my file.
below is the code for date range that is working correctly but how to add other field in this code?
sorry for my bad English and explanation.
thanks

```
Private Sub cmdsearch_Click()

' Search button
Call search
End Sub
'date box
Sub search()
Dim strCriteria As String
Dim task As String
Dim Contractor As String
Me.Refresh
'if date not selected
If IsNull(Me.fromdate) Or IsNull(Me.todate) Then
MsgBox "Please enter the date range", vbInformation, "Date Range Required"
Me.fromdate.SetFocus
Else
'between date filter coding
strCriteria = "([Reply_date] >= #" & Me.fromdate & "# And [Reply_date] <= #" & Me.todate & "#)"
task = "select * from As_built_record where (" & strCriteria & ") order by [Reply_date]"
DoCmd.ApplyFilter task
'for total calcuation coding
Me.texttotal = FindRecordCount(task)
End If
End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmdclear_Click()
'clear button
Dim task As String
Me.fromdate = Null
 Me.todate = ""
 task = "select * from as_built_Record where id is null"
DoCmd.ApplyFilter task
'total calculation coding
Me.texttotal = FindRecordCount(task)
End Sub
Private Sub cmdshowall_Click()
'show all button
Dim task As String '
Me.fromdate = Null
Me.todate = ""
task = "select * from as_built_Record order by [Reply_date]"
 Me.RecordSource = task
 'total calculation coding
 Me.texttotal = FindRecordCount(task)
 End Sub
```

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html. Indentation of code will make it easier to read.

Comment: Have been using Microsoft Access for long time. Split forms are slow and full of problems. I recommend using a regular form with a sub form.